# How can I visualize a histogram graphics in R with the y axis in log10 scale?

Tags: r, graphics, visualization

I want to visualize a histogram graphics in R. The problem is that the distribution of data is highly exponential as in the figure below [image]

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! I will be more careful next time to search better before I add a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the histogram as a variable and then apply log10 to the bin counts. Set the -Inf values to 0 and then plot the new counts.

```
# make histogram of the data
h <- hist(data)

# log10 the counts per histogram bin
h$counts <- log10(h$counts)

# set the -Inf values to 0
h$counts[!is.finite(h$counts)] <- 0

# plot the log10 counts
plot(h)
```